# Moto X app screen suddenly scrolls vertically

Tags: launcher, moto-x

My Moto X, for as long as I've had it, has had the classic panes of apps in the all apps section (where you can just swipe horizontally to browse through the apps).

However, now I have a vertical sliding system with the four recently used apps at the top of the screen.

Is there any way to get back to the old way that stock android had been displaying all apps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Moto X (2014) by default uses [Google Now Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.launcher) as the default launcher.

The [Google quicksearchbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox) was recently updated to give a peek into upcoming Android 6.0 Marshmallow app drawer layout which has vertical scrolling for apps and widgets.

So Uninstalling the updates for app named Google with *package-name* `com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox`  (either in Play-store or in App settings) should bring back the old feature.

[User reviews](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox) dated 24th, 25th September on Google play-store gave me insight on this that the app named Google caused this behavior.

Comment: That launcher shows last updated in August 2014. I wouldn't call it recent, unless there is something I'm failing to see here.

Comment: Actually the app named [Google](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox) which acts as backbone for the launcher was updated yesterday that made the app drawer layout vertical