# Disable "Search apps..." search bar

Tags: applications, 5.0-lollipop, motorola-moto-g2

Device: Moto G 2nd gen (Android 5.0.2).

I'm not sure what I've done (if anything at all), but now when I click on the apps icon in my home screen, instead of my apps being divided between a few pages with me having the ability to scroll right/left between them, now my apps are all in one long page with a search bar above it.

See picture:  [image]

Does anyone know how to revert the situation?

Comment: Which launcher is it? Is it Google Now Launcher? I've heard that they recently introduced the vertical layout.

Comment: Related http://android.stackexchange.com/a/124205/119358

Comment: If you didn't do anything then atleast you must have the default auto-update setting in your Play Store app. So it has updated to the newest version available on Play Store. As it appears on the Play-store comments its the Google App that has been updated to version 5.3 and the UI of the app drawer has been updated from horizontal menu to vertical scrolling along with the search bar at the top in the latest version. You can simple try a different laucher like Apex, Nova for a quick solution. If you don't like other launchers you can try uninstalling the Google app's updates in the Settings.